# Make Python wait until a file exists before continuing

Tags: python

In my code, I write a file to my hard disk. After that, I need to import the generated file and then continue processing it.

```
for i in xrange(10):
    filename=generateFile()
    # takes some time, I wish to freeze the program here
    # and continue once the file is ready in the system
    file=importFile(filename)
    processFile(file)
```

If I run the code snippet in one go, most likely `file=importFile(filename)` will complain that that file does not exist, since the generation takes some time.

I used to manually run `filename=generateFile()` and wait before running `file=importFile(filename)`.
Now that I'm using a `for` loop, I'm searching for an automatic way.

Comment: I think you have a good question here. That being said, keep comments in the comments rather than in the post. Other than that, fresh eyes might expect that the program will not advance from `generateFile` until it's done writing/is importable. Is there multithreading at play here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check and wait until a file exists to read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746750/check-and-wait-until-a-file-exists-to-read-it)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `time.sleep` and I would expect that if you are loading a module this way you would need to `reload` rather than `import` after the first `import`.

However, unless the file is very large why not just generate the string and then `eval` or `exec` it?

**Note** that since your file generation function is not being invoked in a thread it should be blocking and will only return when it thinks it has finished writing - possibly you can improve things by ensuring that the file writer ends with `outfile.flush()` then `outfile.close()` but on some OSs there may still be a time when the file is not actually available.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(10):
    (filename, is_finished)=generateFile()
    while is_finished:
        file=importFile(filename)
        processFile(file)
        continue;
```

I think you should use a flag to test if the file is generate.

Comment: Will it work? From my intuition, it will just continue without doing anything and miss out one set